# In Elasticsearch complete error keyword context in slack web-hook channel

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I want to get complete error keyword context in the slack webhook so what context I have to put in the message body.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Mustache template syntax **{{variable name}}**, you can pass rule values at the time a condition is detected to an action. You can access the list of available variables using the "add rule variable" button. Although available variables differ by rule type, all rule types pass the following variables:

```
rule.id
The ID of the rule.
rule.name
The name of the rule.
rule.spaceId
The ID of the space for the rule.
rule.tags
The list of tags applied to the rule.
date
The date the rule scheduled the action, in ISO format.
alert.id
The ID of the alert that scheduled the action.
alert.actionGroup
The ID of the action group of the alert that scheduled the action.
alert.actionSubgroup
The action subgroup of the alert that scheduled the action.
alert.actionGroupName
The name of the action group of the alert that scheduled the action.
kibanaBaseUrl
The configured server.publicBaseUrl. If not configured, this will be empty.
```

[image]

Here are the action variables for alert and rules body.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/8.6/create-and-manage-rules.html#defining-rules-actions-variables